# Pass a function and yield the result using a class

Tags: python, generator

So this is my code:

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self, lst):
        self.lst = lst

    def generator(self, func):
        for i in self.lst:
            yield func(str(i))

a = Test(['hello', 'world'])

print(next(a.generator(str.upper)))
print(next(a.generator(str.upper)))
```

I'm new to generators and can't see what im doing wrong. I want to pass in a function, in this case the upper() function and yield the result.

The output I get:
'HELLO'
'HELLO'

The output i want:
'HELLO'
'WORLD'

Answer (score 3):

Every time you call a function that uses the `yield` keyword, you get a *different* generator object. If you want to use the same one, then you need to call the function once and store the result in a variable.

```
my_generator = a.generator(str.upper)
print(next(my_generator))
print(next(my_generator))
```

Answer (score 1):

You reconstructed the generator, meaning you started again at the first value. What you want to do is instantiate the generator once, and pass the same reference to `next` multiple times:

```
test = Test(['hello', 'world'])
gen = test.generator(str.upper))

print(next(gen))
print(next(gen))
```